# how can I run npm run lint precommit job for every PR raised against any master repository

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I want to run `npm run lint` as pre-commit job for every PR raised by my fellow engineers to avoid lint issues before or after merge the code.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions (and given that you have to have committed the code to be able to push it to GitHub to trigger anything in GitHub actions, that by definition cannot be pre-commit).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you mean a **pre-commit** or a **GitHub workflow** which runs a linting job. If you are looking for a real [pre-commit hook](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks#:%7E:text=Pre%2DCommit,-The%20pre%2Dcommit&text=You%20can%20use%20this%20hook,t%20break%20any%20existing%20functionality.), then you can do the following:

You can install [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) for creating pre-commit hooks. These hooks will run locally right after you commit something. With that approach you can make sure, that the code which is contributed as a pull request aligns your linting rules.